# application blocking

Tags: php

I have a application which runs over browser ...php application... i need to lock this application to only few machines and laptops that we allow to access. IP locking cannot be done as laptops can be on wifi from outside... Any Idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of locking access, allow access from everywhere, but require a login.

---

In response to your comment: SSL client certificates are probably what you need. See, for example, [here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/howto-securing-a-website-with-client-ssl-certificates-11500) on how to configure this with Apache, or Google for other web servers.

Comment: Login Mechanism is there..What i asked is a client requirement. Is there a way to get system details which are unique to system .

Comment: If a client requires a flawed thing, you have no other option to explaining him that it's flawed and it can't be done.

Comment: Agreed, but in this case it *can* be done, in a way that probably meets the client's requirements. Only systems with the client certificate installed can access the application.

Comment: @Lo'oris - i wanted to explore the options before i tell no to client..

@Thomas  - What exactly do you mean by client certificate ???can u just tell me how to do it..

Comment: @pradeep: I could, but that would take me at least an hour (especially since I have never done this before), while explanations are readily available on the web. I posted a link... why don't you click it?